# OData: last insert ID equivalent

Tags: odata, identity

We're currently interfacing with an OData database, over HTTP.

I need to POST objects (i.e. create them). This works, but how can I get the identifier of the created object?

Comparing this to SQL, how could I get the last insert ID?

Comment: what language/frameworks are you using?

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference, since OData is language agnostic. But it's objc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OData posts responses contain the object that was created. So, you should be able to parse the response and find out the key(ID). The [$metadata](http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/%24metadata) document would tell you which properties are the keys.

Comment: Looks like a great answer, I'll have a look at that !